# How to delete ListViews items by their ID in sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I followed the tutorial here : [Tutorial todo APP](https://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/) and I would like to customize the code nad build training app. My first change is to delete things by their ID in database ( in the example they are being deleted by names ). Here is my current code responsible for deleting items:

```
 // FUNCTION for DELETING EXERCISE
 public void deleteExercise(View view) {
    final View parent = (View) view.getParent();
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure, you want to delete exercise?")
            .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    TextView exerciseTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.exercise_name);
                    String exercise = String.valueOf(exerciseTextView.getText());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    db.delete(ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry.TABLE,
                            ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry.COL_EXERCISE_NAME + " = ?",
                            new String[]{exercise});
                    db.close();
                    updateUI();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create();
    dialog.show();
}

// UPDATING USER INTERFACE AFTER CHANGES IN DB
private void updateUI() {
    ArrayList<String> exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {
            ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry._ID,
            ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry.COL_EXERCISE_NAME,
            //ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry.COL_EXERCISE_DESCRIPTION
    };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry.TABLE, //tablica do zapytań
            projection, //zwracane kolumny
            null,  //columny dla WHERE
            null, //wartosci dla WHERE
            null,//nie grupuj wierszy
            null,//nie filtruj grup
            null); //porządek sortowania
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExerciseContract.ExerciseEntry.COL_EXERCISE_NAME);
        exerciseList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                R.layout.item_workout,
                R.id.exercise_name,
                exerciseList);
        mWorkoutListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(exerciseList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

What would be the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the id anywhere, I'd personally recommend a custom adapter. But for a quick way i think the easiest thing to do is delete it when the users click an item in the list view.

Set the lists views onItemClickListener.

```
        mTaskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Tasks task =(Tasks) mTaskListView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            deleteTask(task.getId());
        }
    });
```

For the delete tasks pass in the _id of the clicked item.

```
    public void deleteTask(long id) {

    //TextView taskTextView = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    //String task = String.valueOf(taskTextView.getText());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE, TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    db.close();
    updateUI();
}
```

In the UpdateUI section change this while loop to also retrieve _id.

```
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int title = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        int _id = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID);

        Tasks tasks = new Tasks();
        tasks.setId(cursor.getInt(_id));
        tasks.setTitle(cursor.getString(title));
        taskList.add(tasks);

    }
```

Lastly create a model for your tasks.

```
package com.aziflaj.todolist.db;

public class Tasks {

    String title;
    int id;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getTitle();
    }
}
```

Also remember to remove the button from the LayoutFile. You could show a dialog before deleting, but this was a quick solution. Ideally i'd recommended creating your own custom adapter. You'll probably have to do that if you wish to keep the button in and delete it that way.

[Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: but I would like to use that buttons in the list and delete the thing in the list after clicking button, how to do that?

Comment: in that case you should make a custom adapter as i have stated.

Comment: :/ I am totally new to android and it seems a little bit complicated. Where should I begin?

Comment: Hi, this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view explains how to create custom adapters

Comment: Yup, after 2 days I did it! Thanks a lot, currently I am working on getting details of list after clicking on position

Answer (score 0):

Create on common method inside your database helper class.

```
public boolean deleteRowData(String tableName, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    open();
    sqLiteDb.delete(tableName, selection, selectionArgs);
    close();
    return true;
}

// ---opens the database---
public NotesData open() throws SQLException {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    sqLiteDb = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDb = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    if (!sqLiteDb.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        sqLiteDb.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
    }
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    if (sqLiteDb != null && sqLiteDb.isOpen()) {
        sqLiteDb.close();
    }
}
```

Now onClick of listView Item do this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         showDeleteAlertDialog(position); // Common method for delete alert dialog
    }
});

private void showDeleteAlertDialog(int arrayPosition) {
    //delete data from
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.warning);
    String message = getResources().getString(R.string.warning_for_delete);

    final android.app.Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme); //this is a reference to the style above
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog); //I saved the xml file above as custom_dialog.xml
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    //to set the message
    TextView sub_message = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_Message);
    TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_Title);
    Button btn_Negative = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Negative);
    Button btn_Positive = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_Positive);

    btn_Negative.setText("Cancel");
    btn_Positive.setText("Delete");

    sub_message.setText("Are you sure you want to delete this>");
    dialogTitle.setText(title);

    //add some action to the buttons
    btn_Positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String selection = YourColumnName + " LIKE ?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = {myArrayList.get(arrayPosition).getID()}; 

            mHelper.deleteRowData(YourTableNAME, selection, selectionArgs);

          // Now just remove that array position from your arraylist (from   activity & adapter arralist too).

            myArrayList.remove(arrayPosition); 
            yourAdapter.yourArrayList.remove(arrayPosition);

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    btn_Negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I am new to Android, here u have a lot of variables that I dont have in my code. Is there any possibility to make some changes in my code and make it working?

Comment: @Mateusz let me know where you get confused in this  ?

Comment: I had more time to spend with android to get this, now I can understand. Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: @Mateusz Glad that you understood this. If my answer is helpful to you, then you can upvote my answer. :)

Comment: Yup, I did it, but my reputation is low now :D